# Spring for Kafka 2.3 setting an offset during runtime for specific listener with KafkaMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have to implement a functionality to (re-)set a listener for a certain topic/partition to any given offset. So if events are commited to the offset 5 and the admin decides to reset the offset to 2 then the event 3, 4 and 5 should be reprocessed.

We are using Spring for Kafka 2.3 and I was trying to follow the documentation on [ConsumerSeekAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerSeekAware.html) which seems to be exactly what I am looking for.

The problem however is that we are using topics that are created on runtime as well. We use a `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` through a `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` for that purpose and I don't know where to put the registerSeekCallback or something alike.

Is there any way to achieve this? I have problems understanding how the class using the `@KafkaListener` annotations maps to the way how listeners are created in the factory.

Any help would be appreciated. Even if it is only an explanation on how these things work together.

This is how the KafkaMessageListenerContainer are basically created:

```
public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, Object> createKafkaMessageListenerContainer(String topicName,
        ContainerPropertiesStrategy containerPropertiesStrategy) {
    MessageListener<String, String> messageListener = getMessageListener(topicName);

    ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(getConsumerFactoryConfiguration());

    KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, Object> kafkaMessageListenerContainer = createKafkaMessageListenerContainer(topicName, messageListener, bootstrapServers, containerPropertiesStrategy, consumerFactory);
    return kafkaMessageListenerContainer;
}

public MessageListener<String, String> getMessageListener(String topic) {
    MessageListener<String, String> messageListener = new MessageListener<String, String>() {

        @Override
        public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> message) {
            try {
                consumerService.consume(topic, message.value());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.log(Level.WARNING, "Message couldn't be consumed", e);
            }
        }
    };
    return messageListener;
}

public static KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, Object> createKafkaMessageListenerContainer(
  String topicName, MessageListener<String, String> messageListener, String bootstrapServers, ContainerPropertiesStrategy containerPropertiesStrategy,
  ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory) {
ContainerProperties containerProperties = containerPropertiesStrategy.getContainerPropertiesForTopic(topicName);
containerProperties.setMessageListener(messageListener);

KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, Object> kafkaMessageListenerContainer = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(
    consumerFactory, containerProperties);
kafkaMessageListenerContainer.setBeanName(topicName);
return kafkaMessageListenerContainer;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please explain further how you are creating your containers and what your listener looks like (show some code). Are you using static `@KafkaListener` beans or doing something dynamic, for example.

Comment: Dynamic. I tried to extract the logic which creates the KafkaMessageListenerContainer. I assume the listeners is the MessageListener which is created anonymously in getMessageListener method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key component is the `AbstractConsumerSeekAware`. Hopefully this will provide enough to get you started...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So59682801Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So59682801Application.class, args).close();
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ListenerCreator creator,
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> template, GenericApplicationContext context) {

        return args -> {
            System.out.println("Hit enter to create a listener");
            System.in.read();

            ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container =
                    creator.createContainer("so59682801group", "so59682801");

            // register the container as a bean so that all the "...Aware" interfaces are satisfied
            context.registerBean("so59682801", ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.class, () -> container);
            context.getBean("so59682801", ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.class); // re-fetch to initialize

            container.start();

            // send some messages
            IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> template.send("so59682801", "test" + i));

            System.out.println("Hit enter to reseek");
            System.in.read();
            ((MyListener) container.getContainerProperties().getMessageListener())
                .reseek(new TopicPartition("so59682801", 0), 5L);

            System.out.println("Hit enter to exit");
            System.in.read();
        };
    }

}

@Component
class ListenerCreator {

    private final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory;

    ListenerCreator(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory) {
        factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(5000L);
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> createContainer(String groupId, String... topics) {
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = factory.createContainer(topics);
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId(groupId);
        container.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(new MyListener());
        return container;
    }

}

class MyListener extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware implements MessageListener<String, String> {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> data) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }

    public void reseek(TopicPartition partition, long offset) {
        getSeekCallbackFor(partition).seek(partition.topic(), partition.partition(), offset);
    }

}
```

Calling `reseek()` on the listener queues the seek for the consumer thread when it wakes from the poll() (actually before the next one).

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use some annotation for spring kafka like this although might be awkward setting the offset in annotation at runtime

```
    @KafkaListener(topicPartitions =
    @TopicPartition(topic = "${kafka.consumer.topic}", partitionOffsets = {
            @PartitionOffset(partition = "0", initialOffset = "2")}),
            containerFactory = "filterKafkaListenerContainerFactory", id = "${kafka.consumer.groupId}")
    public void receive(ConsumedObject event) {
        log.info(String.format("Consumed message with correlationId: %s", event.getCorrelationId()));
        consumerHelper.start(event);
    }
```

Alternatively here is some code I wrote to consume from a given offset, I simulated consumer failing on a message, this is using KafkaConsumer though rather than the KafkaMessageListenerContainer.

```
    private static void ConsumeFromOffset(KafkaConsumer<String, Customer> consumer, boolean flag, String topic) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter offset: ");
        int offsetInput = scanner.nextInt();

        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, Customer> records = consumer.poll(500);

            for (ConsumerRecord<String, Customer> record : records) {
                Customer customer = record.value();
                System.out.println(customer + " has offset ->" + record.offset());
                if (record.offset() == 7 && flag) {
                    System.out.println("simulating consumer failing after offset 7..");
                    break;
                }
            }
            consumer.commitSync();

            if (flag) {
                // consumer.seekToBeginning(Stream.of(new TopicPartition(topic, 0)).collect(Collectors.toList())); // consume from the beginning
                consumer.seek(new TopicPartition(topic, 0), 3); // consume
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    }
```