# How to stop container inside the message listener?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am following the answer of this

[Spring for Kafka 2.3 setting an offset during runtime for specific listener with KafkaMessageListenerContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59682801/spring-for-kafka-2-3-setting-an-offset-during-runtime-for-specific-listener-with)

I want to stop the container if I receive a certain offset. How can I stop the container inside "onMessage"?

Also, is it possible to set an initial offset for a container?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to configure a `ContainerStoppingErrorHandler` and throw an exception.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#container-stopping-error-handlers

To stop the container in the listener itself, you need to perform the stop on a different thread, to avoid a temporary deadlock.

Using a `TaskExecutor`, you can use code like this...

```java
this.executor.execute(() -> container.stop());
// isRunning is false before the container.stop() waits for listener thread
int n = 0;
while (container.isRunning() && n++ < 100) { // NOSONAR magic #
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100); // NOSONAR magic #
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        break;
    }
}
```

You can get a reference to the container from the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean, using the listener `id`.

Versions 2.5.11, 2.6.5, 2.7.0 and later have a new container property `stopImmediate`.

When true, stopping the container will happen when the listener returns (additional records returned by the previous poll will not be delivered until the container restarts.

With earlier versions, or if it is false, the container will stop when all records from the poll have been passed to the listener.